# Creating a Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

When you create a windows forms application, you are by default given a

```
Form1
```

If you then create your own windows form, that form then becomes a child of the From1.

How can I create a Form which is not a child of the default Form1? Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: In the visual solution and under its project, if you add as many forms you may want, they never become child of other. Instead they are independent of each other. Go to Program.cs and see for the line Applicaton.Run() method. There you can specify which form you want run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Form1` is inherited from partial class `Form`. If you want to create a your form you must inherit from base class `Form`.

Answer (score 1):

When you create any other form in windows project, it is not the child of the first form. I am not sure how do you get the child of the windows form.

I think, you are not getting the second form as the start up form, that is the reason you might be thinking it as the child form.

Comment: Yes, well, I have a form1, and a form2, when I close the form1 the form2 is closed also.

Comment: It is because you have started the form2 from form1. TO achieve this, you need to use the concept of MDIParent. And both the forms form1 and form2 will be managed from MDIparent, so none of the form will be dependent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inherit from the Form class. See the inheritance hierarchy for the Form class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx and now see the inheritance hierarchy for the Control class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx. This means that the Form is a specific type of Control and if you want to create a custom Form, inherit from the Form class. You can then add or remove controls in your Form using the Controls.Add or Controls.Remove methods.